# i want to install box cutter on my pc ,but there is a problem

Tags: add-on

when i click install boxcutter ,it install and shows in blender,but when i check the box to activate box cutter it shows error message.when i install the same add on in blender 2.9 it works fine but when i install it in 3.2 it shows the error message anyone please give me the right way to install the addon,Thanks in advance.[image: this is the error it swhows,how to solve this.]

Comment: could you share the error log?

Comment: I don't use Boxcutter, but are you installing the latest version (7.1.9)?

Comment: The clue is in the last line, so I know what the problem is, but I don't know a general solution.  You've previously tried to install box cutter and the install has partially worked; leaving a bit of a mess.  So now when you try the install it sees the mess and gives up.  To clear the mess you have to unregister the classes that were registered previously.  Perhaps uninstalling and removing box cutter, and trying again would work but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Marty fours , but it's not working I have uninstalled box cutter but it's not working,then I have uninstalled blender also but also don't worked . If there is an way to manually unregister the classes thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for reply yousuf Chaudhry but how can I share the error log to you?

Comment: Thank you John eason the box cotter I was trying to install is a little bit older version.